# How to Test Load time of a page without Varnish using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

May I know how to test a page's load time without varnish?

Question In Precise:  I want to have N number of hits for page directly to the server (without Varnish) so that i can find the load time of that page precisely!

Answer (score 0):

Individually you can get the Response Time in your listener you have added (e.g. View Results Tree) or you can create HTML report. 
[Generate HTML Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Response time = Load Time is a difference between time when request was sent and time when response has been fully received.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://varnish-cache.org/intro/index.html#the-basics)

> Varnish Cache is a web application accelerator also known as a caching HTTP reverse proxy. You install it in front of any server that speaks HTTP and configure it to cache the contents.

So when Varnish is in place the call sequence looks like:

```
user -> varnish -> page
```

You can remove interim `varnish` step so the sequence would look like:

```
user -> page
```

All you need to do is to determine `page` hostname or IP address and point JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to hit the page directly, not via the varnish. In varnish terms this is called [backend server](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/tutorial/backend_servers.html) and you can figure the underlying `page` address from the configuration file (or just ask around)

---

Be aware that as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages

so you will need to perform some extra configuration in order to properly handle:

- [Cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [Headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
- [Embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)
- [AJAX requests](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)
- [Cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- etc.

So make sure JMeter is properly configured, otherwise your measurements will not be correct and reliable.